# OpenLdap configuration

Tags: authentication, kerberos, openldap

Simple enough question; is there a way you can configuare your ldap server so it only accepts kerberos authentication and rejects any other type.

I'm almost 100% certain this can be done, i just do not know how - something in a config file no doubt.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the require option in the configuration, or olcRequires for the ldif format.

As per documentation, for **require**

> Specify a set of conditions (separated
>   by white space) to require (default
>   none).  The directive may be 
>   specified  globally  and/or 
>   per-database;  databases  inherit
>   global  conditions, so per-database
>   specifications are additive.  **bind**
>   requires bind operation prior to
>   directory operations.  **LDAPv3** requires
>   session to be using LDAP version 3. 
>   **authc** requires authentication prior to
>   directory operations.  ***SASL*** requires
>   SASL authentication prior to 
>   directory  operations.   **strong** 
>   requires  strong authentication prior
>   to directory operations.  The strong
>   keyword allows protected "simple"
>   authentication as well as SASL
>   authentication.  **none** may be used to
>   require no conditions (useful to clear
>   out globally set conditions within a
>   particular database); it must occur
>   first in the list of conditions.

and for **olcRequires**

> Specify  a  set  of  conditions  to 
>   require (default none).  The directive
>   may be specified globally and/or
>   per-database; databases inherit global
>   conditions, so per-database
>   specifications are additive.  **bind**
>   requires bind operation prior to
>   directory operations.  **LDAPv3** requires
>   session to be using LDAP version 3. 
>   **authc** requires authentication  prior 
>   to  directory  operations.   ***SASL*** 
>   requires  SASL  authentication prior
>   to directory operations.  **strong**
>   requires strong authentication prior
>   to directory operations.  The strong
>   keyword allows protected "simple"
>   authentication as well as SASL
>   authentication.  **none** may be used to
>   require no  conditions  (useful to
>   clear out globally set conditions
>   within a particular database); it must
>   occur first in the list of conditions.

SASL is what you want here, because Kerberos v5 implements GSSAPI.

Other than this, I wouldn't be able to tell you because I don't know any configuration that restricts the kind of authentication allowed in an LDAP server.